# NDK with C++ no implementation found error

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have looked for everywhere but no exact explain be found.
the error like below:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ensHG.png)

the head file like below:
1.com_BTC_ui_JNI.h
[hfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jo6CN.png)

the cpp file like below:
2.addcomputer.cpp
[cppfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeHlS.png)

the Android.mk like below:
[Androidmk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkBAA.png)

the java invoke code like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI4V2.png)

Comment: I cannot know whether you can see the pictures.

Comment: I have tried many ways like 1.delete the words "JNIEXPORT"  2.delete the words "JNIEXPORT" and "JNICALL" 3. rename the method name from Jave_com_BTC_ui_JNI_plus to Jave_com_BTC_ui_JNI_plus__II 4.rename the method name from Jave_com_BTC_ui_JNI_plus to Jave_com_BTC_ui_JNI_plus__II_2,but no one helps.

Comment: What ABI are you targetting? I think I had a similar error when trying to use a library compiled for armeabi-v7a on a device supporting arm64-v8a.

Comment: Android.mk file show the target abis.

Comment: Do not post screenshots of code, build scripts or error messages. Post them as properly formatted text.

Comment: But the edit tool is not easy to use.the \r\n after every line of code make the follow code escape from the code format area.

Comment: I think I'm very nearly of success.Just a little . That's caused by compiler ,I guess......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the header file named with "com_BTC_ui_JNI",and moved the extern "C" to my cpp file.Now I don't any more have a header file ,then compile and run ,everything goes well.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is named `Jave_com_BTC_ui_JNI_plus` while it should be `Java_com_BTC_ui_JNI_plus`.

Comment: I had recorrect the mistake.But error be there still.

Comment: No implementation found for java.lang.String com.BTC.ui.JNI.getString() (tried Java_com_BTC_ui_JNI_getString and Java_com_BTC_ui_JNI_getString__)
05-25 04:59:20.264 2020-2020/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

Comment: What does the error message mean?Does my code has any syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your method implementations in `extern "c"` in the addcomputer.cpp file otherwise the C++ compiler does name mangling.

Comment: This is defined in the [header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jo6CN.png) file

Comment: I had solved this problem.It's not because of the extern "C" ,but because of the automatically generated header file.I just deleted the header file named with whole java class name,and moved the extern "C" to my cpp file.The error gone.Everything is OK!